# Cask 'adoptopenjdk11' definition is invalid: 'appcast' stanza failed with: Calling the `appcast` stanza is disabled

Tags: adoptopenjdk

[![% brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk11

Error: Cask 'adoptopenjdk11' definition is invalid: 'appcast' stanza failed with: Calling the `appcast` stanza is disabled! Use the `livecheck` stanza instead.
Please report this issue to the adoptopenjdk/openjdk tap (not Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core), or even better, submit a PR to fix it:
/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/adoptopenjdk/homebrew-openjdk/Casks/adoptopenjdk11.rb:9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLLq6.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLLq6.png)